# How does "Ne pas se sentir convaincu de [qch]" = "I was aware of [sth]" instead of "I did not feel convinced of [sth]"?

Tags: sens

The following comes from a book written by Jung, and translated by Gallimard into a book titled *Dialectique du Moi et de l'inconscient*; it is from one of the Prefaces to that book:

> Cela représentait un simple essai, et **je ne me sentais pas trop
> convaincu de ses insuffisances.**

The same sentence from an English translation, titled *The Relations between the Ego and the Unconscious*, translated by R.F.C. Hull in a book called *Two Essays in Analytical Psychology*:

> It was a mere attempt, **of whose inadequacy I was painfully aware**.

---

If I try to translate the French version, I would come up with something like:

> This represents a simple attempt, and I don't feel very convinced of its inadequacies.

and DeepL gives:

> This was a mere attempt, and I did not feel too convinced of its inadequacies.

The translation by DeepL (and me) seem to be the opposite of what the English version says! That is, DeepL's translation is saying that Jung was not "convinced" of its inadequacies; that is, that Jung did not think it had strong inadequacies.

Obviously, DeepL's translation is incorrect, because it does not match the English version.

Why does "Je ne me sentais pas trop convaincu de ses insuffisances" not mean "I did not feel too convinced of its inadequacies", but instead means something closer to "I was painfully aware of its inadequacies"?

Comment: Tried DeepL that gave me "It was a simple test, and I didn't feel too convinced of its shortcomings." I didn't get the same as you but anyway it matches the meaning of the French sentence, like yours did. The English translation you got - from a book I presume - seems weird to me, that's why it would be great to have the original sentence in German. You wouldn't happen to have it, would you?

Comment: I am not sure how to find the German title, actually! (The Wikipedia article for this book doesn't give it to me). If I knew the German title, Google might be able to give me the PDF. To be honest, I'm not 100% sure what the English sentence you got from Deep, "It was a simple test, and I didn't feel too convinced of its shortcomings.", or the English sentence I got from DeepL even means. I *thought* "not being convinced of its shortcomings" means the same as "I'm not convinced that it *has* shortcomings". Is that what the French sentence means to you?

Comment: German title *Die Beziehungen Zwischen dem Ich und dem Unbewussten* but couldn't find the whole text in German. Internet archive has it in French and gives exactly the French sentence you are giving. It's Gallimard's edition and [the translator](https://data.bnf.fr/fr/12340038/roland_cahen/) is a Jung specialist  and **I** would entirely trust his translation. To me the two sentences we both got from DeepL mean the same, and to me it sounds quite the opposite of the translation you quote in your question. The French sentence means he wasn't really convinced of the shortcomings in his test.

Comment: @None I appreciate your input! I guess I'm surprised that different translators could translate the same sentence with opposite meanings, but I guess this is evidence that this happens!

Comment: @None: The original German: *Es war ein bloßer Versuch, von dessen Unzulänglichkeit ich nur allzusehr überzeugt war.* (Found by searching in the snippet view Google books version for *Versuch*.)  I don't know enough German to fell competent in translating this myself, but DeepL's translation agrees with the English version.

Comment: I think the problem might come from the word *nur*. In English, a word-for-word  translation might be *of whose inadequacies I was only too convinced*, but I can't think of a French word for *only* that you could use like that. [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/allemand-francais/nur/291776) translates *nur* as *ne ... que*, which could explain where the spurious negation came from.

Comment: @None: in English, *only* serves as an intensifier here; it doesn't really mean *only*. I'm assuming the same is true of German, but I know very little German, and I could be totally wrong.

Comment: @silph Can you please add to your question where your English translation comes from (book, edition, translator etc.). I'm going to leave a message ton he chat on German Language to send someone over here.

Comment: @PeterShor French would say something like: je **n**'étais **que** trop convaincu par... German and English leave no doubt as to what *von dessen/of whose* refer to. *Ses* could leave a doubt but when reading the [whole paragraph](https://archive.org/stream/JungCarlGustavDialectiqueDuMoiEtDeLinconscient/Jung%2C%20Carl%20Gustav%20-%20Dialectique%20du%20moi%20et%20de%20l%27inconscient_djvu.txt) it clear refers to *essai* too.

Comment: Would some words be missing : *je ne me sentais pas trop convaincu **à cause** de ses insuffisances*. Or a word added (but that would be  an unsual error)  *je me sentais que  trop convaincu de ses insuffisances*

Comment: I am fluent in German."It was a mere attempt, of whose inadequacy I was painfully aware." is a correct translation of "Es war ein bloßer Versuch, von dessen Unzulänglichkeit ich nur allzusehr überzeugt war.", unless "Versuch" actually means "experiment". (Hard to say without more context.)

Comment: One doesn't translate from a translation. Ergo, this question should not be here. No one does that. Interpreters sometimes do that, it's called relay interpretation. This here is a fool's errand. Sites like Deepl are not designed to deal with highly intellectual texts, anyway. And can be **very misleading**.

Comment: @Lambie: What exactly is highly intellectual about the OP's sentence? It seems to be written in pretty ordinary language to me (in French, German, and English). And further, DeepL got everything right in this case; it's the French translator who got it wrong.

Comment: @PeterShor The OP's sentence is a translation of Jung. Jung, to say the least, is highly intellectual. The French is probably badly translated. Just like most of the initial translation of Freud **into French**. In any case, the question should be closed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about German>French translation followed by a French>English of the same text. This is really unthinkable. Relay translation does not work and is certainly not a subject for this site.

Comment: @Lambie Presumably, both the English and French were translated directly from the German. I believe my question is on-topic for this site: I saw a French sentence that I did not understand; I sought to understand it using various strategies that I knew. One strategy was using DeepL, and one was finding an English translation. I think these are valid strategies, and certainly an English translation would be more reliable than DeepL. I saw that the English didn't match what I thought the French said, and I sought to correct this contradiction. Askng clarification of a Frnch sentence is on-topic

Comment: The French into English is a translation and that is what you are questioning. That is off-topic.

Comment: @Lambie are you saying that if i chose to continue to try to read Jung in French (note: i won't! it's too difficult for me! the *English* translation is too difficult for me, too!), that it will not work out well if i hope to understand the French better by consulting an English translation? i thought it would have been a good idea, given that translators of Jung (whether French or English translators) should usually come up with compatible translations? the trouble is that DeepL is my only other strategy for understanding difficult French sentences, and as you say, it doesn't always work well

Comment: Close votes have been cast. Please let the stubborn badgering come to an end now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The context of this sentence is sufficiently complete if the beginning of the whole paragraph is included, as well as some lines that follow it.

> Dans l’essai publié en 1916 sur La Structure de
> l’inconscient mentionné plus haut, j’essayais, pour la
> première fois, d’apporter une synthèse résumant
> l’ensemble du processus. **Cela représentait un simple
> essai, et je ne me sentais pas trop convaincu de ses
> insuffisances.** Les difficultés inhérentes à l’objet à
> étudier étaient telles que je ne pouvais espérer, en une
> brève communication, en venir à bout et leur rendre
> justice. C’est pourquoi, avec la ferme intention de
> reprendre, à l’occasion, l’ensemble de cette étude dans
> un cadre plus ample, je m’étais limité à cette
> « communication provisoire ». Douze années
> d’expériences supplémentaires me permirent, en 1928,
> de remettre sur le métier mes constatations et mes
> descriptions de 1916.

Jung is speaking about one of his early essais, and concerning it he says "Les difficultés inhérentes à l’objet à étudier étaient telles que je ne pouvais espérer, en une brève communication, en venir à bout et leur rendre justice"; that is to say that he **perceived important difficulties** in the treatment of this subject, and that **he had no hope of surmounting them in the short piece** he had decided to write. This does not point to the would-be fact that he could have doubted the reality of the inadequacies, but on the contrary to the fact that he was only too convinced of them, which corroborates the english translation. It appears then that the French translation is in error. This is corroborated by the fact that "allzusehr" is translated by "que trop" and that the negation "nicht" does not appear in the German (Es war ein bloßer Versuch, von dessen Unzulänglichkeit ich nur allzusehr überzeugt war). Sans la négation "allzuseher" se traduirait par "que trop" et ce ne serait que lorsque "nicht" figure dans la construction que "ne pas trop" is right.

> ([bab.la](https://fr.bab.la/dictionnaire/allemand-francais/allzusehr))  « allzusehr » en français allzusehr {adv.}
> **que trop**
>
> ♦  Meiner Ansicht nach sollten wir mit diesem Gebäude **nicht** allzusehr prahlen. → En ce qui me concerne, je dirais qu'il **ne** faut **pas** être trop bougon vis-à-vis de ce bâtiment.
> ♦ Während „gerade die ersten beiden Episoden packende Thriller“ gewesen seien, stehe bei diesem Film „allzusehr die Botschaft im Vordergrund“.  → Le négociateur ne réussit que trop bien dans une mission aussi délicate.

(See the examples of translation in the above reference)

- Cela représentait un simple essai, et je ne me sentais que trop convaincu de ses insuffisances.

Answer (score 5):

If I had to align the French with the original German, I would read *de* as "by" rather than "of":

> I was not much convinced by its shortcomings. ~ I was hardly convinced by its shortcomings. Its shortcomings failed to convince me. For its shortcomings, I was not convinced. Because of its shortcomings, I was not convinced.

Thus:

> Cela représentait un simple essai, et ses insuffisances ne m'ont pas trop convaincu.

It seems to me an attempt to capture the flavour of the German in a not very natural rendering in French. But it's not an impossible logical construction if read in a sufficiently ironic tone. Compare this exchange:

> Weren't you impressed by my poetry?
>
>
> No. I am not much impressed by doggerel and sentimentality.

Comment: swayed by None's and LPH's logic, i was convinced that the French sentence was probably a mistranslation. do you also think it actually is a mistranslation, or do you instead think it's more likely that the reading that you outlined here is likely what was intended by the French translator?

Comment: @silph My original opening was "If I was forced to reconcile the French and the German", but it pushed one or two words onto the next line on my screen, and my OCD took over and I replaced it with a version that was more ambiguous but more visually pleasant (to me...). I do think the reconciliation would be forced. I don't know why the translator chose this wording.

Comment: i do find it interesting to see your idea of the forced reconciliation with the given wording, though, so thanks for writing the answer!